# Can't see alpha channel in png using GIMP

Tags: gimp, png, blender

I created an RGBA image as png file using Blender. When opening image with GIMP, not everything is visible.

Here's the original png file created with Blender:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I9rF.png]

Here how does it looks in GIMP:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZlgJ.png]

Here's how it should look like (use command: `ffmpeg -i original.png out.mp4` [using original image] to see for yourself):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smljb.png]

The third image is a movie, using ffmpeg to convert original image to movie.

How to view all data in png file using GIMP? Is there any other graphics software that will read .png file correctly?

Comment: Can you get anything else to see the "rays" effect? Just tested your original file in a couple of browsers (Chrome, IE8) over a black background and both looked like your GIMP example. So did Paint.net.

Comment: That's the problem. The rays are initially visible in Blender, after that only ffmpeg can see it. I also did try other software, but no luck. It's weird that most of the software can't handle this type of png format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. The GIMP and other software works perfectly well, it's the Blender fault. Somehow Blender doesn't save the alpha channel correctly for effects (in my case it was Glow effect). The rays had alpha set to 0, so they're invisible. If you open that png file in GIMP, view Channels and edit Alpha channel you can reveal the hidden content.

[image]

Comment: Sorry we couldn't be more help to you Mario. Glad you've fixed the problems though

Comment: So the movie was just showing the full RGB image, the alpha having been discarded?